# ViewController transition bottleneck in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, instruments

When I tap on a specific UITabBarItem to switch ViewControllers, the transition takes about 4 - 5s.

There is no heavy processing being done, so this leads me to believe that the code is simply inefficient.

After having taken a look inside Instruments as suggested in the comments, I have pinpointed the following process to be taking ~> 2500 ms

```
Running Time    Self (ms)       Symbol Name
2485.0ms   44.3%    0.0     
TDescriptorSource::CopyDescriptorsForRequestFromArray(__CFArray const*, __CFDictionary const*, CFComparisonResult (*)(void const*, void const*, void*), void*, unsigned long, bool) const
```

and

```
Running Time    Self (ms)       Symbol Name
3070.0ms   54.7%    0.0      -[UIStackView initWithCoder:]
```

What does this mean?

Comment: is the delay happening first time or always ? device or simulator ?

Comment: Check out the instruments app, use the time profiler tool to study which objects are getting allocated and deallocated.

Would certainly help if you could provide some code.

Comment: @Mr.T both device and simulator!

Comment: @TheAppMentor I just posted the results from Instruments

Comment: @Mr.T and this only happens the first time

Comment: Even i face the issue , same delay for the push transition for the first time!!! I didnt find any solution yet!!! If you come to know, plz let me know

Comment: @Mr.T My problem is with transitioning between `UITabBarController` tabs. It's not a push transition..

Comment: Can you post an example project that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: An easy way would be to put a couple of NSLog() statements with a timestamp in each view's ViewDidAppear(), ViewDidDisapear() to further try and narrow down the bottleneck.

Run Analyze and check for any transition/animation warnings.

Maybe try a System Trace profile too.