# UISegmentedControl to Display Multiple Datasets on UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `ViewController` in my `UITabBarController` that takes a gnawing 5-8 seconds to load.

No heavy processing, no significant callback chains and no network calls.

I asked this question earlier:

[ViewController transition bottleneck in UITabBarController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33963768/viewcontroller-transition-bottleneck-in-uitabbarcontroller)

And I think I have pinpointed the source of the problem, so I will go into more detail here.

I have a `UITableView` whose dataSource changes based on the value of a `UISegmentedControl`. I am displaying friend requests, and the segmented control manages the display of `Outgoing` and `Incoming` ones.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    friendRequestsToDisplay = FriendRequestManager.instance.incomingFriendRequests

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    self.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    self.refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "refreshRequests:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    self.tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)

    incomingFriendRequests = FriendRequestManager.instance.incomingFriendRequests
    outgoingFriendRequests = FriendRequestManager.instance.outgoingFriendRequests
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return friendRequestsToDisplay.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let bookRequest = self.friendRequestsToDisplay[indexPath.row]

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("RequestCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? RequestCell {
        cell.configureCell(friendRequest, isAnIncomingRequest: isAnIncomingRequest)
        return cell

    } else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

According to breakpoints and for some odd reason, `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `numberOfRowsInSection` gets called exactly twice the number of total `friendRequests` loaded

And `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` takes about 4 seconds to load with a breakpoint.

[Here are the results from the Time Profile in Instruments:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2o93.png)

Anybody have an idea as to what could be the source of the lag?

Comment: Use the time profiler instruments tool to analyse your app

Comment: @Paulw11 just edited with a screenshot of the results of the Time Profiler (link at the bottom)

Comment: It seems to be taking a long time to load a custom font, but that is just a guess

Comment: @Paulw11 How could I help you help me identify the problem ?

Comment: all of the methods shown in the time profile screen shot were system methods; how does this correlate to your code?  Until you can identify where in your code the time is being spent you are just guessing.

Comment: @Paulw11 Nevermind, the font was the problem! Yeah!!! If you write it up as an answer I'll accept it...

Comment: @Paulw11 For future notice, how do I identify where in my code the time is being spent ???

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial - http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode - use the settings under "drilling deep"